# Kivy: resetting toggle buttons to "normal" on re-entering screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm working on a kivy app that includes a screen with toggle buttons in it. I'd like to know how to reset the state of any of these buttons that happen to be "down" to "normal" every time the user enters that screen.

In order to keep the GUI code separate from the rest of the application, I'd prefer to be able to reset the buttons from within my screens.kv file. Is there a way of doing so?

Here's the releveant section of my screens.kv:

```
# Solution code, based on przyczajony's answer:
<ScreenThree>:
    on_enter:  
        button1.state = 'normal'
        button2.state = 'normal'
        button3.state = 'normal'
        button4.state = 'normal'
        button5.state = 'normal'
#End of solution code, beginning of original question code:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20

        Label:
            id: label
            text: root.explanationText
        ToggleButton:
            id: button1
            text: root.button1Text
            on_state: 
                if self.state == 'normal': root.button1Up()
                else: root.button1Down()
        ToggleButton:
            id: button2
            text: root.button2Text
            on_state: 
                if self.state == 'normal': root.button2Up()
                else: root.button2Down()          
        ToggleButton:
            id: button3
            text: root.button3Text
            on_state:
                if self.state == 'normal': root.button3Up()
                else: root.button3Down()
        ToggleButton:
            id: button4
            text: root.button4Text
            on_state: 
                if self.state == 'normal': root.button4Up()
                else: root.button4Down()           
        ToggleButton:
            id: button5
            text: root.button5Text
            on_state: 
                if self.state == 'normal': root.button5Up()
                else: root.button5Down() 
        Button:
            id: button6
            text: root.button6Text
            on_release: root.manager.current = "screen4"
```

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Screen widget](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) has an event called `on_enter` (and `on_pre_enter`), which is dispatched upon entering a screen. You can reset state of the buttons there. Example:

```
Screen:
    on_enter:
        button1.state = 'normal'
        button2.state = 'normal'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        ToggleButton:
            id: button1

        ToggleButton:
            id: button2
```

You could also do this in a loop, but I think it wouldn't look good.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for. But when I try it I get an error message ending in `if current_property[:3] == 'on_': TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` Perhaps I'm missing an import? Any suggestions?

Comment: @R.Duke Delete the comment '# or on_pre_enter', it causes issues. I will also delete it from the answer.