# How to target canvas.before in kv

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In a button i have made a rounded button with `canvas.before`, and it changes colors as it should. The line is:

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: btn_color_not_pressed if self.state=='normal' else btn_color_pressed
    RoundedRectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        radius: [40]
```

The variables **btn_color_not_pressed** and **btn_color_not_pressed** are made with `#:set` in the start of the kv-file

I have tried to target the line with `self.canvas.before.Color.rgba`, as i am used to normally, but i get following error:

`AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.CanvasBase' object has no attribute 'Color'`

How do i target that line from within kv and replace the variables ... or if necessary from the python file.?
How do i target the `source: "some_file.jpg` under `Rectangle`?

My goal is that when a user has clicked an option all the button colors (and maybe the background) in the app must change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the variables created in `kv`. Once your app is running, those variables no longer exist. You can, however, use a [Property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) that is created in `kv` (or python) as an attribute of a class (or the `App` itself). Such `Properties` continue to exist while the `App` is running, and kivy recognizes such `Properties` and will automatically handle changes to those `Properties`. An example is to create a new class that extends `Button` and has `Properties` like you want:

```
<-MyButton@Button>:
    # create the desired properties
    btn_color_not_pressed: [.5, .5, .5,1]
    btn_color_pressed: [.25, .25, .25, 1]

    canvas:
        Color:
            # reference the above properties
            rgba: self.btn_color_not_pressed if self.state=='normal' else self.btn_color_pressed
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [40]
        
        # this is copied from style.kv to show the Button text
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)

# actually make an instance of the new MyButton class
MyButton:
    btn_color_not_pressed: [1,0,0,1]
    btn_color_pressed: [0,1,0,1]
    text: 'Button Test'
```

The `<-MyButton@Button>` creates a new class (`MyButton`) that extends `Button`. The prepended `-` indicates that the default `canvas` instructions for `Button` are not to be used and the provided instructions are used instead. Those new `Properties` can be changed in python code as usual. You can use a similar approach for the `source` property.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution (here: [Kivy: resetting toggle buttons to "normal" on re-entering screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383562/kivy-resetting-toggle-buttons-to-normal-on-re-entering-screen))

It's kind'a ugly, but it works..

Give every button an id ... and then use `on_enter` for each button and set and change the state.

In the code above it would mean:

```
on_enter:
   button1.state = "down"
   button1.state = "normal"
   button2.state = "down"
   button2.state = "normal"
   button3.state = "down"
   button3.state = "normal"
   button4.state = "down"
   button4.state = "normal"
```

It works ... but it is not pretty :|